# Static Class, Static Constructors and static properties

Tags: c#

I have a static class that has only static properties and a static constructor. When I try to access or set the value of property (with a backing field) the static constructor is not called. However, if I define a static method and try to call it the constructor is executed.

I believe properties are just syntactical sugar and are internally translated as methods. So why does the runtime treats them differently? My class define is given below:

Edit: I have removed the code where I was initializing the value of _fileEncodingText inline.

Edit: The constructor is called but the property is not set. This is probably because "a static constructor runs exactly zero or one times, and runs before a static method call or instance creation in its type". Igor Ostrovsky and Eric Lippert have explained it in their blogs

1. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/05/03/10159682.aspx
2. http://ericlippert.com/2013/01/31/the-no-lock-deadlock/

   internal static class AppSettings
   {
       static AppSettings()
       {
           FileEncodingText = "UTF8";
       }

   ```
   private static string _fileEncodingText;
   public static string FileEncodingText
   {
       get { return _fileEncodingText; }
       set
       {
           string oldValue = _fileEncodingText;
           _fileEncodingText = value;

           try
           {
               FileEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(value);
           }
           catch (System.Exception)
           {
               _fileEncodingText = oldValue;
               FileEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
           }
       }
   }

   public static Encoding FileEncoding { get; private set; }
   ```

   }

Comment: Have you got a usage example?

Comment: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx

Comment: The constructor is called when you set a property

Comment: Since the class is static, I don't see the point of having the static constructor. Especially since you're already assigning `"UTF8"` to the class variable anyway. You would normally use a static constructor in a non-static class.

Comment: Properties are definitely not "just syntactical sugar", they're well recognized by the CLR as *properties* and not as *methods*.

Comment: out of interest you can use `FileEncoding.EncodingName` to get the name of the encoding. (you dont really need to store encoding as string just use the available property)

Comment: two answers that cannot reproduce and another having to make assertions what the OP means. :/

Comment: @Gusman I am setting the property in another class, but the constructor is not called.

Comment: @mikeyq6 .. I want to set a default of the constructor... Hence the static constructor. Irrespective of the requirement, I was expecting that the constructor will execute if I try to access/ set the property.

Comment: I just copy/pasted your class, set the FileEncodingText and it called the constructor, maybe you mixed up FileEncodingText and FileEncoding properties?

Comment: @Gusman no I didn't. FileEncoding property is readonly for consumer classes. In my mail when the code "this.lblFileEncoding.Text = AppSettings.FileEncodingText;" executes, the static constructor is not called.

Comment: @haim770 .. Properties become getters and setters method (get_<property_Name>, set_<property_Name>) , possibly, decorated with some attributes to differentiate them from normal methods. But I still expect the static constructor to execute.

Comment: @Sandeep, My comment only intended to object the claim that properties are merely "syntactic sugar". They're not.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. It is a bug in my code. I have updated my question with the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I try to access or set the value of property (with a backing
>   field) the static constructor is not called.

I'm unable to replicate the issue you're seeing and the above doesn't appear to be happening on my example (see the .NET Fiddle link - https://dotnetfiddle.net/ikIhw3).

It appears that an exception is being thrown when setting the FileEncodingText property which sets the `_fileEncodingText` backing field back to UTF8. Could this be the cause of what you're seeing?

The following (taken from the aforementioned .NET Fiddle):

```
internal static class AppSettings
{
    static AppSettings()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In constructor");
        FileEncodingText = "UTF8";
    }

    private static string _fileEncodingText = "UTF8";
    public static string FileEncodingText
    {
        get { return _fileEncodingText; }
        set
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting value: " + value);
            string oldValue = _fileEncodingText;
            _fileEncodingText = value;

            try
            {
                FileEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(value);
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("Exception");
                _fileEncodingText = oldValue;
                FileEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            }
        }
    }

    public static Encoding FileEncoding { get; private set; }
}


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        AppSettings.FileEncodingText = "UTF16";
        Console.WriteLine(AppSettings.FileEncodingText);
    }
}
```

Results in the following output:

```
In constructor
Setting value: UTF8
Exception
Setting value: UTF16
Exception
UTF8
```

Updated:

Drilling down into the exception even further, this is the output I'm seeing in the fiddle. Perhaps it's worth adding some logging to see if the exception is being thrown on your end?

```
Run-time exception (line 45): The type initializer for 'AppSettings' threw an exception.

Stack Trace:

[System.ArgumentException: 'UTF8' is not a supported encoding name.
Parameter name: name]
  at AppSettings.set_FileEncodingText(String value): line 34
  at AppSettings..cctor(): line 9

[System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'AppSettings' threw an exception.]
  at Program.Main(): line 45
```

As you can see, this is being thrown within the constructor when setting the default `UTF8` value?

Comment: I don't get any exception. I am debugging this code in visual studio and the application runs without any issue. I have set a breakpoint in the constructor but the breakpoint is not hit.

Comment: That's odd. It's definitely throwing an exception in the fiddle provided in the link. 

Have you tried setting the `FileEncoding` property to something out of the ordinary within the catch block and verified it's not changed after the property has returned its value?

Comment: Yes.. if I set it to some invalid value, say "Ansi", it throws an exception and the encoding is set to the default value UTF8. In case, I set it to some valid value, say windows-1252, it works with any issue.

Comment: Oh ok, that answers that questions then.

Comment: I've just updated my answer in include the exception that's being thrown. It appears to be related to the default `UTF8` value being set within the constructor.

Comment: You are right.. I still don't get any TypeInitializationException.. and I am able to use the static class after that

Answer (score 3):

I cannot reproduce the issue.

The following program prints

```
AppSettings - Static constructor called.
UTF8
```

as expected.

Therefore the answer would appear to be that you have made a mistake somewhere in your testing.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace Demo
{
    internal static class AppSettings
    {
        static AppSettings()
        {
            FileEncodingText = "UTF8";
            Console.WriteLine("AppSettings - Static constructor called.");
        }

        private static string _fileEncodingText = "UTF8";
        public static string FileEncodingText
        {
            get { return _fileEncodingText; }
            set
            {
                string oldValue = _fileEncodingText;
                _fileEncodingText = value;

                try
                {
                    FileEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(value);
                }
                catch (System.Exception)
                {
                    _fileEncodingText = oldValue;
                    FileEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                }
            }
        }

        public static Encoding FileEncoding { get; private set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(AppSettings.FileEncodingText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a winform application and the code in the constructor is not called.

Comment: @Sandeep It won't make any difference whether it's a winform app or not. You must be overlooking something somewhere.

Comment: You are write.. the static constructor executes.. but the call to the property doesn't work.

Comment: @Sandeep Then I would suspect that an exception is being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx) documentation

> A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.

note that the documentation said "static members" so there is no difference between "Static Property" and "Static Method" [in your case]